# Stream data from one kafka topic to another using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have been trying to stream some sample data using pyspark from one kafka topic to another (I want to apply some transformations, but, could not get the basic data movement to work). Below is my spark code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col

import time

confluentApiKey = 'someapikeyvalue'
confluentSecret = 'someapikey'

spark = SparkSession.builder\
      .appName("repartition-job") \
      .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1')\
      .getOrCreate()

df = spark\
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "pkc-cloud:9092") \
      .option("subscribe", "test1") \
      .option("topic", "test1") \
      .option("sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN")\
      .option("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
      .option("sasl.username", confluentApiKey)\
      .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(confluentApiKey, confluentSecret))\
      .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")\
      .option("sasl.password", confluentSecret)\
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
      .option("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO")\
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "true").load()

df.printSchema()

query = df \
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
  .writeStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "pkc-cloud:9092") \
  .option("topic", "test2") \
  .option("sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN")\
  .option("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
  .option("sasl.username", confluentApiKey)\
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(confluentApiKey, confluentSecret))\
  .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")\
  .option("sasl.password", confluentSecret)\
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
  .option("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO")\
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint").start()
```

I have been able to get the schema printed well.

```
|-- key: binary (nullable = true)
|-- value: binary (nullable = true)
|-- topic: string (nullable = true)
|-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
|-- offset: long (nullable = true)
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

And when attempting to write to another Kafka topic using `writeStream`, I see the below logs and dont see the data being written and spark shuts down.

```
22/02/04 18:29:26 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to file:/tmp/checkpoint/metadata using temp file file:/tmp/checkpoint/.metadata.e6c58f93-5c1c-4f26-97cf-a8d3ed389a57.tmp
22/02/04 18:29:26 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file file:/tmp/checkpoint/.metadata.e6c58f93-5c1c-4f26-97cf-a8d3ed389a57.tmp to file:/tmp/checkpoint/metadata
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting [id = 71f0aeb8-46fc-49b5-8baf-3b83cb4df71f, runId = 7a274767-8830-448c-b9bc-d03217cd4465]. Use file:/tmp/checkpoint to store the query checkpoint.
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Reading table [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable@3be72f6d] from DataSourceV2 named 'kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@276c9fdc]
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://spark-sample-9d328d7ec5fee0bc-driver-svc.default.svc:4045
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
22/02/04 18:29:27 WARN ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Starting new streaming query.
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Stream started from {}
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
22/02/04 18:29:27 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
....
....
....
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-7acecef5-0f0b-4b9a-af81-c8aa12f7fcad
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version: 2.4.1
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId: c57222ae8cd7866b
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka startTimeMs: 1643999368467
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-641f2e65-8f10-46b9-9821-d3b1f3536c0e/spark-1a103622-3329-4444-8e69-40f5a341c372/pyspark-59e822b4-a4a4-403b-9937-170d99c67584
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO KafkaConsumer: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-75381ad2-1ce9-4e2b-a0b7-18d6ecb5ea8b--2090736517-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-75381ad2-1ce9-4e2b-a0b7-18d6ecb5ea8b--2090736517-driver-0] Subscribed to topic(s): test1
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-641f2e65-8f10-46b9-9821-d3b1f3536c0e/spark-1a103622-3329-4444-8e69-40f5a341c372
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
22/02/04 18:29:28 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.
```

Also, sometimes, I do see the below logs where the kafka connection fails to establish.

```
22/02/06 04:50:55 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0] Bootstrap broker pkc-.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
22/02/06 04:50:56 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0] Bootstrap broker pkc-.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
22/02/06 04:50:57 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0] Bootstrap broker pkc-.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
22/02/06 04:50:58 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-fc21e146-82f0-4fc7-a2da-34f3e8f70026-289148490-driver-0] Bootstrap broker pkc-.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) What are you expecting it to print? 2) You shouldn't be casting anything if you just want to copy data 3) You should really be using Confluent Replicator or MirrorMaker rather than Spark for copying topics, or Kafka Streams to do simple transforms in the same cluster

Comment: My use case restricts me in copying using Replicators (Destination kafka topics restricts the usage). Regarding the printing stuff, I just want to output to the console so I can understand the connection is working and the spark job is running fine. Yes, I can remove the casting, but, just trying different stuff to be able to console output. @OneCricketeer

Comment: And what about Kafka Streams or Python `faust` library rather than Spark? Your code has `pkc-cloud` and your logs have `pkc-.confluent.cloud`. If these are indeed different, that's part of your connection problem

Comment: My bad. I just removed the cluster details in the logs manually. if the kafka topic has data that requires distributed system to handle the data movement, does `faust` handle it?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. My comment was more related to the fact that you're consuming and producing to the same cluster. Sure, Spark can do it (given the right configs), but there's more purpose-built solutions for it. If you must do it with Spark, I assume you'll need JKS files and passwords for SSL communications

Comment: I realized the bug is with Spark version 3.0.0 where all the packages are not published to the executors and so `kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule` is not available. I believe I have to use a latest image of spark since the issue was fixed as of 3.1

Comment: Hello @ZZzzZZzz ,  even we are facing same problem with same code you have posted above, have you found a solution? if yes, please post the solution it will be helpful.. thank you.

Comment: @ChiranjeeviB In my case the credentials were wrong and it started to work after fixing them.